# How to export Safari history to either Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

The title pretty much explains. I've tried searching and couldn't find any reliable info. Almost all posts in the internet are asked many years ago.

Comment: `cp -rf /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Safari/History.db-wal /Users/$(whoami)/Library/Safari/History.db  ~/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick script:

https://github.com/Roman2K/hist_safari2chrome

- Move Safari's history database at a convenient place.
- Create a database for Chrome using this script and replace the Chrome's under ~/Library with the new one.
- Increase  Firefox limits of import using https://superuser.com/questions/1635171/firefox-doesnt-import-all-history-from-chrome/1635172#1635172
- Import history from Chrome in Firefox.

---

Edge can import Safari history. Give it Full Disk Access, and then import history, bookmarks etc. Remove FDA now.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/import-browser-data-from-safari-to-microsoft-edge-in-macos-mojave-6e39ccd9-7d8a-8d79-1574-87083b316bb4

Then Firefox can import Edge history: create a new profile (or not, if it's a new download), import data from the appropriate Edge profile.

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-data-another-browser

Then Chrome/Brave can import from Firefox profile in the same manner.

- https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019782291-How-do-I-import-or-export-browsing-data-

Delete the bookmarks folder and history items added by Firefox though.